# continuously check URL until string is present, run javascript code when found

Tags: javascript, jquery, intervals

i need some help with this code. i want to read the current URL, and when the URL contains "#_ThankYou" in it, I want to add a new  to an existing  on the page and that div contains some javascript that will display an ad from an ad vendor. i have the following but i think i might be caught in an infinite loop. not sure i coded this correctly. anyone have good suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.eddyCookieCount = 0;
window.eddyNumberAttempts = 0;
window.myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("#_ThankYou") > window.eddyCookieCount) {
            jQuery('div.thankyou-container').append('<div>' + vm_load({
                "displayId": "12584", // Numeric unique ad display Id
                "publisherId": "33927", // Publisher ID 
                "campaign": "9380", // Numeric Publisher Campaign Id
                "maxResults": "3",
                "areaofstudy":     JSON.parse(jQuery.cookie('CategorySubCategorySpecialty')).CATEGORIES[0].text.replace('Business','1').replace('Criminal Justice & Legal','3').replace('Education','5').replace('Fine Arts & Design','2').replace('Health & Medicine','8').replace('Liberal Arts & Humanities','5').replace('Math, Science & Engineering','9').replace('Public Affairs & Social Sciences','13').replace('Religious Studies','5').replace('Technology','9').replace('Vocational Training',''),
                "md": "1"
            }) + '</div>');
    window.eddyNumberAttempts++;
    if (window.eddyNumberAttempts > 60) {
      window.eddyCookieCount = jQuery.cookie('CategorySubCategorySpecialty').length;
      window.eddyNumberAttempts = 0;
    }
  }
  else if (jQuery.cookie('CategorySubCategorySpecialty').length < window.eddyCookieCount) {
    window.eddyCookieCount = jQuery.cookie('CategorySubCategorySpecialty').length;
  }
}, 50);
</script>
```

Comment: Do you trigger the addition of _#_ThankYou_ yourself? Instead of waiting for that condition to be fulfilled, what prevents you from just running the function at the same time you add that hash?

Comment: @blex - no, the addition of the hash is part of moving from one step in a funnel to the next, so it only happens once a user gets to the thank you step of the funnel. don't ask why the funnel was built this way, i don't know, but it doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to do an interval to watch for the hash to be added.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
     if (window.location.search === "#_ThankYou") {

    }
});
```

In your code, I do not see you ever cancelling the interval when you are in the state when the url is changed so it keeps firing. you need to cancel it.

```
window.clearInterval(window.myInterval)
```

Comment: hmmm, ok @epascarello, where would i add the code to cancel the interval? sorry...this is not my forte. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, where I have to check a token in the URL on view change.

The way I worked is below code, which doesn't seem good to use, but it is worked on selector basis:

```
$('.nav ul li a').click(function() {
    setTimeout(changeurl, 4000);        
});

function changeurl(title, newurl) {
    if (window.location.hash == '') {
        return window.location.hash = '#/dashboard';        
    }

    var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + window.location.hash;

    if (history.pushState) {            
        window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
    }
}
```

Finally, I modified the code as such:

```
var token = window.location.search;

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
     if (window.location.search === token) {
         setTimeout(changeurl, 4000);
    }
});
```